# Starting cells of asp:table from same base but heights are different

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp:table and I am dynamically adding data in it. Now depending on certain conditions I want cells to have different heights. I am getting different heights of cells but the problem is cells are not starting from the same base.
I am attaching the image below of what I am getting:

[image]

Now in the image all cells are starting from different bases but I want that they all should start from the bottom line. Actually I am trying to make a graph with the help of asp:table

Comment: Tried using ASP.Net Chart ?

Comment: Please show your HTML and CSS. Otherwise, it's hard to say anything useful.

Comment: ya but no chart type is available to make above kind of chart.Please help me how i can remove the below space and can start each cell from same base

Comment: i havent used any css just given height and backcolor of cell from codebehind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impossible to say without seeing your HTML, but this isn't really what tables are for.
You should really use `<DIV>`s or an `inline-block` style element.

However, I assume you tried style `vertical-align: bottom;` on the containing `<tr>` element?